# OLAP window functions in DB2

Tags: db2, aggregate, window-functions, olap

I am using DB2 z/OS 11.1.5. According to [this reference](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0023461.html), OLAP functions such as `first_value` should be supported at least in DB2 9.7. However, when trying to execute the query

```
declare global temporary table T (reference integer, val integer) on commit preserve rows;
insert into session.T values(1, 10);
insert into session.T values(2, 20);
select first_value(val) over (order by reference) from session.T;
```

I am given the error

`NO AUTHORIZED FIRST_VALUE NAMED  HAVING COMPATIBLE ARGUMENTS WAS FOUND. SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, DRIVER=4.18.60. 2) [Error Code: -514, SQL State: 26501]  THE CURSOR SQL_CURLH200C1 IS NOT IN A PREPARED STATE.`. I am aware of the [listing](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/codes/src/tpc/db2z_n.html) of error codes. However, these descriptions do not help me to understand the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up Db2 (Db2 for Linux, Unix and Windows) and Db2 for z/OS.

Db2 9.7 is LUW (Linux, Unix and Windows) and FIST_VALUE is available on these OS'es.

Db2 for z/OS does not support FIRST_VALUE.

Comment: @Bubaya, z/os documentation can be found at: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_olapspecification.html

Comment: @Lennart Ah, thank you two! I wasn't aware that the features differ that much.